# How do you make prepareForReuse() work right?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview, prepareforreuse

I have a table view with ten cells. Each of them contains an image view. When scrolling, sometimes images start jumping from one cell to another - I guess reuse does not work. I tried to reset the image to nil in `prepareForReuse()`, but the problem persists.

```
catImageView.image = nil
```

I also reset `indexPath` in `cellForRowAt`, but that didn't work either.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? SearchCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
    let cat = cats[indexPath.row]
    cell.setup(cat)
    cell.catImageView.image = nil
    return cell
}
```

In rxSwift for this I cleaned `disposedBag`. What can be done in this case?

Comment: What's `cell.setup(cat)` code, especially the part on how is the the image?

Comment: there is an image loading by url

Comment: And what happens when the image is loaded? If you're holding a reference to the cell for that method, and you're scrolling the list, then the cell that has been reused is going to get the image set with the old cat's image once it loads.

Comment: @jrturton yes, the problem was in the method of loading image - I changed it on kingfisher framework and the problem gone away, so thank you!